# Creating a variable width <pre> element with optional scrollbars

Tags: html, scrollbar, pre, variable-width

I want to add  div to my website which has variable width, and that it will display scroll bars when the width is smaller than the longest line.
I tried wrapping such a fixed width  element, in a variable width (100%)  but that didn't work. I got the scroll bars on the entire page.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Yaron

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `overflow` CSS property to the problematic `div`:

```
#problematic-div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This defines what happens to content that overflows the content area of an element. For the value scroll, user agents are supposed to provide a scrolling mechanism whether or not it is actually needed; thus, for example, scrollbars would appear even if all content can fit within the element box.

You can try some examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't really help, as it doesn't show the scroll bars for that div, just hides the overflow.

Comment: @Yaron: Just for clarification, what you want is to show the scroll bars when the inner elements are greater than the parent div width and hide it otherwise?